# How to update value in table in database, laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to update a value in a database in laravel4. It's a bit of a cornercase, I have just a single entry in the database with a session-id in it. it's used to authenticate against facebook.

This is the model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

    class Accesstoken extends Eloquent {

    public static function createpost($token)
    {
        $accesstoken = new Accesstoken;
        $accesstoken->accesstoken = $token;
        $accesstoken->save();
    }

    public static function update($token)
    {
        $accesstoken = Accesstoken::find(1);
        $accesstoken->accesstoken = $token;
        $accesstoken->save();
    }
}
```

It's the second function that is wrong. If I try to add it before doing a migrate, I can't migrate and if I try to call it like this

```
Accesstoken::update($access_token);
```

I get the following error, why?

Cannot make non static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() static in class Accesstoken

Comment: `Eloquent\Model` already implements a method `public function update(array $attributes = array())` that isn't static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an update() method in Eloquent already. Try something like

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

    class Accesstoken extends Eloquent {

    public static function createpost($token)
    {
        $accesstoken = new Accesstoken;
        $accesstoken->accesstoken = $token;
        $accesstoken->save();
    }

    public static function updateToken($token)
    {
        $accesstoken = Accesstoken::find(1);
        $accesstoken->accesstoken = $token;
        $accesstoken->save();
    }
}
```

And

```
Accesstoken::updateToken($access_token);
```